# FilePath points to mapped drive instead of actual server name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I use this formula: `=LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"),1)-1)`
to retrieve the file location of the open workbook, it always gives me something like

C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3

when in reality, I want

\\ausp-fil\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3.

ausp-fil is mapped onto the C: drive, and that's why it's showing up like that, but is there a way to make the formula retrieve the file location with the server name? I may have mapped ausp-fil to C: but I'm sure other people haven't.

Comment: have you tried simply removing the mapped drive letter and opening the file from the direct path? Or is there something you are using that requires it to be mapped?

Comment: @braX I have not - but the thing is, even if I don't have it mapped, other people who're going to use this workbook will. I can't have everyone un-map their drives.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will be able to do it using just a formula, but you can use this VBA function to convert the mapped drive letter to its UNC path. VBA Functions *can* be used in formulas.

```
Function GETNETWORKPATH(ByVal DriveName As String) As String
    Dim objNtWork  As Object
    Dim objDrives  As Object
    Dim lngLoop    As Long

    Set objNtWork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set objDrives = objNtWork.enumnetworkdrives

    For lngLoop = 0 To objDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
        If UCase(objDrives.Item(lngLoop)) = UCase(DriveName) Then
            GETNETWORKPATH = objDrives.Item(lngLoop + 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function

Sub kTest()

    MsgBox GETNETWORKPATH("P:")

End Sub
```